# My angular onclick is not taking me to ajax server code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have written a `onClick` on button for bringing data from the server but it is not taking me to the `GetMPFilter` function which is written in server side

```js
$scope.GetFilter = function () {        
        var strZone = $('#SAPExecutive_R4GState').val();
        var strUtility = $('#ddlUtility').val();

        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null, '').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="' + full.objectid + '">'
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONENAME", "MAINTENANCEZONENAME"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONECODE", "MAINTENANCEZONECODE")
        ]
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
            method: "POST",
            url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "/App/GetMPFilter",
            dataType: 'json',            
            data: JSON.stringify({ strZone: strZone, strUtility: strUtility }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(10);
    }
});


Server code

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetMPFilter(string strZone, string strUtility)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Filters ObjFilter = new Filters();

            dt = ObjFilter.GetMPFromState(strZone, strUtility);

            var MpList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                          select new
                          {
                              //Action = "",
                              MZONENAME = Convert.ToString(dr["MAINTENANCEZONENAME"]),
                              MZONECODE = Convert.ToString(dr["MAINTENANCEZONECODE"]),                              
                          }).ToList();

            return Json(MpList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default customBtn" ng-click="GetFilter();"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filter</button>
```

Please suggest where I am wrong

Comment: you issue a POST request to an endpoint called GET ... naughty ....

Comment: sorry didn't got you

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu: please suggest where I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please use these changes i posted. I hope this will resolve your issue. Thank you.

```
  $scope.GetFilter = function () {        
            var strZone = $('#SAPExecutive_R4GState').val();
            var strUtility = $('#ddlUtility').val();

            $scope.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null, '').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="' + full.objectid + '">'
                }),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONENAME", "MAINTENANCEZONENAME"),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("MAINTENANCEZONECODE", "MAINTENANCEZONECODE")
            ]
            $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
                method: "POST",
                url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "/App/GetMPFilter",
                dataType: 'json',            
                data: "{strZone:'" + strZone + "',strUtility:'" + strUtility + "'}", 
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
            })
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(10);
        }
    });
```

Here is Simple example of button Click:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    {{msg}}
    <a ng-href='#here' ng-click='go()' >click me</a>
    <div style='height:1000px'>

      <a id='here'></a>

    </div>
     <h1>here</h1>
  </body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.go = function() {

    $scope.msg = 'clicked';
  }
});
```

Comment: tried getting error as `DTColumnBuilder is not defined`

Comment: I supposed to issue was there only there in ajax, And i have updated the ajax parameters.

Comment: You may be missing "DTColumnBuilder" in your angular.

Comment: so where to add that ? sorry i m very much new to angular that's why

Comment: Please have a look at this:http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withAjax

Comment: any example on button click ??

Comment: here is my fiddle which I tried https://jsfiddle.net/sLm1d8u9/ but getting error as `The controller with the name 'ServerSideProcessingCtrl' is not registered.` Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187988/discussion-between-b-n-and-ali-hassan).

Comment: can u come on chat, i guess its 10 mins discussion. please

Comment: Really sorry, I can't come into the chat discussion. Thank you.